# how to position a header as if its still inside the table

Tags: css, positioning

I'm using this jquery plugin called [jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) and I'm trying to make it work with tables so that only the repeating part will have scrollbars on it(the elements inside the tbody). Here's my code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>DVD Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Book</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="container">

        <?php
        while($row = $query->fetch_object()){ 
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->dvd_title; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->category; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->book; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to make the tbody as the container but I didn't get the result. I also wrapped the repeating part with paragraph(which does the trick for others) but it doesn't work either.

Now I'm looking for a css solution for this. Is there any way that I could make the table headers retain their styling as if they are inside the table? 
The problem here is that if I use the plugin on the whole table the table headers are also hidden when I scroll, like this:

[image]

I tried using relative positioning but it hides the headers the moment it goes out of the area covered by the table.

Comment: can u show your css html code in jsfiddle.net //........

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu: See my answer below for the pure css solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### PURE CSS SOLUTION:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="tbl-title"> 
        <li class="seperator">DVD Title</li>
        <li class="seperator">Category</li>
        <li>Book</li>          
    </ul>

    <div id="tbl-data">
        <?php
            while($row = $query->fetch_object()){ 
        ?> 
        <ul class="tbl-row"> 
            <li class="seperator">
                <span><?php echo $row->dvd_title; ?></span>            
            </li>
            <li class="seperator">
                <span><?php echo $row->category; ?></span>            
            </li>
            <li>
                <span><?php echo $row->book; ?></span>
            </li>              
        </ul>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#tbl-title,
.tbl-row {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;   
}

#tbl-title li,
.tbl-row li {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-family: tahoma;    
}

#tbl-title li{
    background: #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;    
}

.tbl-row li {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align:left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;    
}

.tbl-row li span { 
    display: block; 
    padding: 0px 10px; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.seperator {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

/* Styles specific to this particular page */
.scroll-pane {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

### [SEE RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/XbjAe/) - (updated with jscrollpane implementation)

​

Answer (score 1):

Add you scroll main div inside the td which has colspan="3'

```
    <table>        
            <tr>
            <th>DVD Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Book</th>
            </tr>        
            <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
            <div class="scroll-pane jspScrollable" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 760px; " tabindex="0">        
            <div class="jspContainer" style="width: 760px; height: 200px; "><div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px; width: 740px; top: -110.93331909179688px; ">
            <table>
<tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->dvd_title; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->category; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->book; ?></td>
            </tr>
</table>
            <div class="jspVerticalBar"><div class="jspCap jspCapTop"></div><div class="jspTrack" style="height: 200px; "><div class="jspDrag" style="height: 77px; top: 42.507159651996936px; "><div class="jspDragTop"></div><div class="jspDragBottom"></div></div></div><div class="jspCap jspCapBottom"></div></div></div></div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```